# Load a controller after main controller loaded completely

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have an angular application. In all of my HTML pages, I have 2 controller: "mainCtrl" and "thatPageCtrl"

I need to define queue for controllers. I want to launch mainCtrl first, after complete execution of mainCtrl, I want to load thatPageCtrl.

I'm authenticating users in all the route in mainCtrl, and I want to  launch thatPageCtrl if authentication is true. And I'm binding some data to all pages in mainCtrl and I need to  launch thatPageCtrl after these data bind completely from mainCtrl.

How can I do that?

My angular config code:

```
/* Assign Angular Application Name */
var dashboardApp = angular.module("dashboardApp" , ['ngRoute' ,  'ngFileUpload']);

/* Configuration Ajax Routing */
dashboardApp.config(['$routeProvider' , '$locationProvider' ,  function($routeProvider , $locationProvider){

$routeProvider.
   when("/home" , 
      {templateUrl : "/home.html"}).
   when("/signin" , 
      {templateUrl : "/signin.html"}).
   otherwise({templateUrl : "/home.html"});

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

}]);
```

Comment: are you using angular-ui-router?

Comment: No, I don't know this library. Can you tell me a solution without angular-ui-router?

Comment: you don't know which routing library are you using inside your angularjs app?

Comment: I know which library I`m using: angular + angular-route + angular-cookie. I mean was I have not heard about "angular-ui-router".

Comment: can you add in your question the code you  have when defining a state please?

Answer (score 0):

Inside each block you can define a resolve block. This block will specify data that will be resolved before that the state will be render.

Then you can simply inject that property inside the controller.

Here an example:

```
when("/home" , 
      {
  templateUrl : "/home.html",
  resolve: {
    MY_DATA: function() { return 'Hello World!'; }
  }
})
```

Then just inject MY_DATA inside the controller associated to the home and you should have the value there.

I hope it helps

Comment: This is possible but I have 19 routing address my authentication function is 32 lines. I can`t inject all 32 lines  in each routing!! how can I do that?

Comment: First move your 32 lines of authentication inside a main service and inside the resolve eventually call that method, so it's just one line of code and you group the auth in one method. Then, to better understand stand, your need is to know inside each page if logged in or not, or you want to completely hide and not load the page if not logged in?